# best way to support zeroconf in a URI syntax?

Tags: uri, zeroconf

what is the best way to support zeroconf names in the location segment of a URI design?

RFC 3986 (Uniform Resource Identifier (URI): Generic Syntax) makes no mention of zeroconf and i fear the URI syntax is not designed to work beyond DNS resolution.

the ideal answer syntax will:

1. conform to the generic URI syntax
2. handle zeroconf names with multi-byte characters

Comment: What do you mean by Zeroconf DNS names? mDNS names like `foo.local`? Please provide an example of a name you want to represent as a URI.

Comment: want alternatives to illegal syntax:     scheme://"Tony's server"/bookmarks/bm1          scheme://"主要な開発"/bookmarks/bm1

Comment: Are you asking how to embed the host name `Tony's Server` in e.g. a http-URL? Legally you can’t. If that is not important: just do it.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some options:

```
dnssd://local/_printer._tcp/Fancy printer/
dnssd://Fancy printer._printer._tcp.local
```

These strings are IRIs, not URIs, in order to address i18n issues.

Comment: And what is `dnssd` supposed to do? I’ve seen that scheme in CUPS, but totally underspecified in the docs. To sum it up: this scheme is as good as any random letter combo (outside of CUPS).

Answer (score 1):

a nested URI is another approach that is backward compatible.  a nested URI defines the location for use with discovery protocols like zeroconf.

see 'nested uniform resource identifiers' manuel urena and david larrabeiti

however i dont find evidence this approach in is wide use.

Comment: It's one of only two options, sadly: (1) create something that isn't a legal URI that has sub-schemes, like "http://[mdns:Nick's PC]/index.html", or (2) bite the bullet and create zillions more URI schemes if the output string simply has to be legal according to the URI syntax, eg "http-mdns://Nick's PC/index.html". Basically, the nested approach may not be widely used, but it's going to have become so if mDNS gets more popular.

Answer (score 0):

A universal resource identifier is a generic way to locate a resource. For internationalization, you may want to check on IRI, which is almost the same, but allows for full Unicode compatibility. The reason that it doesn't mention Zeroconf is that URI is a generalized protocol. Zeroconf may use URIs are part of its protocol for discovery, but URI will never use specific implementation in its protocol (you won't find ftp:, https:, mailto:, skype: etc in there either)

Zeroconf is a protocol to automatically configure your network and discover available services. It consists of three parts, address selection (part of IPv4/6), name resolution (mDNS) and service discovery (UPnP (Microsoft), DNS-SD (Apple)). Modern operating systems support all of this out of the box.

If we take UPnP, the discovery is done based on a URI, iirc. The returned information is given in XML. XML can be any Unicode encoding. If you're a device driver manufacturer, you can place any character in there. The final phase may be presentation, which is a URL but that's optional.

A URI / URL both support internationalized characters, but only escaped and not in the domain name part.

-- Abel --